# 2 dimensional array undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I created a function generates a table :

```
function TabGen(sRow){
 var sResultat = "<table border = 1 px solid black>";

for(var iCompt = 0; iCompt<arguments.length; iCompteur++)
{
    sResultat += ("<td>" + arguments[iCompteur]+ "</td>")
}
sResultat += "</table>";
return sResultat;
}
```

Then I created a function which uses a 2 dimensionnal array to print out on the screen a table with 3 rows 4 columns. This :

```
function AfficheTab() {

var aTab = [[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,3]];

for(var iCompt=0; iCompt < aTab.length; iCompt++)
{
  return(aTab); 
}
}
```

Why am I getting an undefined? If it's wrong, how should I resolve this problem?

Print function :

```
(function (){

            var aLesDiv = document.querySelectorAll("#global div");

            aLesDiv[0].innerHTML = TabGen((AfficheTab(aTab)));


        }) ();
```

Comment: where is your <tr> ?

Comment: You're defining a function called AfficheTab that does not receive any parameters and you're passing `aTab` as parameter. This will never work.

Comment: `"<table border = 1 px solid black>"`will not be a valid HTML code...

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` itself is an array. If you want to use array, use arguments[index][arrayIterator]
As you use a 2D array, you have to use 2 arrayIterators.

```
function TabGen(sRow){
   var sResultat = "<table border = 1 px solid black>";

    for(var iCompt = 0; iCompt<arguments[0].length; iCompteur++){
    sResultat += ("<td>" + arguments[0][iCompteur]+ "</td>")
  }
  sResultat += "</table>";
  return sResultat;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

See your function, what it is returning? a row or the matrix? The matrix...

```
function AfficheTab() {

    var aTab = [[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,3]];

    for(var iCompt=0; iCompt < aTab.length; iCompt++)//useless loop
    {
      return(aTab); //the code stops in the first loop and return [[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,3]]
    }
}
```

So your `TabGen` can handle all by doing :

```
function TabGen(aTab) {
   aTab.forEach((row) => {
       row.forEach((cell) => {
         //Do something with your row values (cell) 
       });
   });
   return false;//return your return stuff
}
```

I suppose that you want a table so...

```
function TabGen( aTab ) {
   var html = [];

   html.push( '<table border="1">' );   

   aTab.forEach(( row ) => {
       html.push( '<tr>' );

       row.forEach(( cell ) => {

        html.push( '<td>',cell,'</td>' ); 

       });

       html.push( '</tr>' );
   });

   html.push( '</table>' );

   return html.join( '' );
}
```